# LPTHREADS: Pointer to a structure or address of a structure?

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads

I have a program that creates N processes, and each of those processes creates M threads.

I also have  a structure that needs to be passed to the thread function.

---

When I create the M threads like this:

```
thread_args_t** thread_arg = malloc(sizeof(thread_args_t*)*m);
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    thread_arg[i] = malloc(sizeof(thread_args_t));
    thread_arg[i]->child_id = child_id;
    thread_arg[i]->thread_id = i;

    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_function, thread_arg[i]);
}
```

the program works flawlessly.

---

However, if I create an array of that structures and I pass the address of the array, the program doesn't work:

```
thread_args_t* thread_arg = malloc(sizeof(thread_args_t)*m);
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    thread_arg[i].child_id = child_id;
    thread_arg[i].thread_id = i;

    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_function, &thread_arg[i]);
}
```

---

Here's the thread process code:

```
void* thread_function(void* x)
{
    thread_args_t *args = (thread_args_t*)x;

    /* TODO: protect the critical section using semaphore(s) as needed */

    //Do stuff

    free(x);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

---

So, what's the problem here?

I got a runtime error on the `thread_function` talking about an invalid pointer.
That's a screen of the output:

(I noted that the error types are not always the same)

```
> [Main] Initializing file accesses.log...closed...file correctly initialized!!!
[Main] Creating named semaphore /sem_cs...Done /sem_cs: 1
[Main] Creating named semaphore /sem_ready...Done /sem_ready: 0
[Main] Creating named semaphore /sem_start...Done /sem_start: 0
[Main] Creating named semaphore /sem_closed...Done /sem_closed: 0
mainProcess All are ready. Firing. BAAAAAANG!
mainProcess RONFRONF
Child N.4 bursting 10 threads
Child N.0 bursting 10 threads
Child N.1 bursting 10 threads
Child N.2 bursting 10 threads
[Child#1-Thread#2] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#1-Thread#2] 1 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#1-Thread#2] File accesses.log closed!!!
Child N.3 bursting 10 threads
[Child#0-Thread#0] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
*** Error in `./riepilogo_errato': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001c18640 ***
[Child#0-Thread#0] 0 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#0-Thread#0] File accesses.log closed!!!
======= Backtrace: =========
Child N.0 joining threads[0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6([Child#1-Thread#1] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
+0x777e5)[0x7f0ebaacf7e5]
[Child#1-Thread#1] 1 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#1-Thread#1] File accesses.log closed!!!
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0[Child#4-Thread#0] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
*** Error in `./riepilogo_errato[Child#4-Thread#0] 4 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#0-Thread#4] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6[Child#0-Thread#4] 0 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#0-Thread#4] File accesses.log closed!!!
*** Error in `./riepilogo_errato': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001c18650 ***
[Child#2-Thread#0] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#2-Thread#0] 2 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
======= Backtrace: =========
[Child#2-Thread#0] File accesses.log closed!!!
[Child#0-Thread#1] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#0-Thread#1] 0 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#0-Thread#1] File accesses.log closed!!!
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f0ebaacf7e5]
[Child#4-Thread#0] File accesses.log closed!!!
[Child#2-Thread#1] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#2-Thread#1] 2 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#2-Thread#1] File accesses.log closed!!!
Child N.2 joining threads[0]
[Child#4-Thread#9] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#4-Thread#9] 4 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#4-Thread#9] File accesses.log closed!!!
[Child#3-Thread#0] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#3-Thread#0] 3 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#3-Thread#0] File accesses.log closed!!!
Child N.3 joining threads[0]
[Child#3-Thread#1] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#3-Thread#1] 3 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#3-Thread#1] File accesses.log closed!!!
*** Error in `./riepilogo_errato': free(): invalid pointer[Child#3-Thread#2] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#3-Thread#2] 3 appended to file accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
[Child#3-Thread#2] File accesses.log closed!!!
*** Error in `./riepilogo_errato[Child#3-Thread#7] File accesses.log opened in append mode!!!
```

Comment: Is lower case 'm' equal to 'M'? You iterate over some M but you allocate 'm' items in the array.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll edit it.

Comment: Can you show the exact error message in your question?

Comment: Obviously, wait a minute

Comment: You changed your mallocs. did you also change your free?

Comment: Free are included in the teacher code so we should't change them. It's not the same to free a pointer or an address?

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of text - copy/paste the text itself.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix it

Comment: Do you know how the teacher `free`s the memory`

Comment: "Free are included in the teacher code so we should't change them".  In the original code there are `m` allocations for `thread_args_t` structs.  Presumably there are `m` frees for those allocations?  In your revised code there is a single allocation for the `thread_args_t` structs (a single array of `m` elements).  There cannot be `m` frees - only a single call to `free()` is valid in that case.  So if you don't change the code that frees the `thread_args_t` structs there will be a problem.

Comment: Why do you have to allocate memory (or is the `malloc`also done by the teacher?) but not free it yourself. This does not make sense at all.

Comment: He free the alloc in a function that we only use.
The scope of the exercise is not about malloc or free but about threads, so they "save us" from the free.

Comment: He does a single free

Comment: Please show all relevant code pieces or else we have to just guess what the problem is.

Comment: It is a very traditional threading bug.  By the time the thread starts running, depending on how long that takes, the local variable is no longer in scope.  So &thread_arg[i] points to random garbage.  Sadly this isn't guaranteed to be the case, it still *might* have a valid pointer, so it gets to be hard to debug.  Not an issue with the first snippet because the passed pointer points to stable memory on the free store.

Comment: Ok i'm gonna post the thread process.
Monday I'll ask it also to my teacher so we will see if it's a bug of their code or something mine

Comment: @HansPassant Right, but this would only happen if the join(if any is out of scope of the malloced pointer. Roberto where do you join the threads?

Comment: No I don't join the threads, they die after a semaphore fire a signal

Comment: so the main programm might end before the threads?

Comment: This can't happen because I fire the end of the threads

Comment: I will stress this again please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) else we just have to do guess work. Multithreading is quite a complex issue with a lot of traps to fall in so help us help you by posting a complete but specific example. specfic means remove everything not related to the problem. My answer is the best bed so far but there might be more mistakes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169413/discussion-between-kami-kaze-and-roberto-aureli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thread code frees the passed pointer:

```
void* thread_function(void* x)
{
    thread_args_t *args = (thread_args_t*)x;

    free(x);  // <-- HERE
}
```

However, that isn't a pointer that was returned from an allocation function - it's a pointer within your array.

That's Undefined Behaviour.

The fix is simply to remove the call to `free()`.

Comment: BTW, it's not necessary to write a cast like that when assigning from a `void*`.

Comment: Ok. I asked the teacher: that's the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see ( my last usage of pthreads is a bit dated), there is nothing wrong here. Your error messages indicate that you try to `free` your `malloc`ed memory multiple times.

As you just use one allocated space for everything instead of one allocation for every thread I assume that you still try to `free` it after closing every thread. But without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this will be hard to check.

Basically your first program uses an "array" of pointers. And then allocates memory for every pointer. These get passed to your threads.

```
int **arr = malloc(sizeof *arr *2);
arr[0] = malloc(sizeof **arr);
arr[1] = malloc(sizeof **arr);
```

Now you have three allocations they have to be freed on their own.

```
free(arr[0]);
free(arr[1]);
free(arr); // this has to be the last or else you lose your reference for the other pointers.
```

The second programm is better to my mind you just get an array of your arguments (this reduces fragmentation) and you just have to free one allocation.

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr *2);
...
free(arr);
```

But as the free is done by another function (not programmed by you), it probably expects the first implementation and tries to free it as shown above. Which will try to free not allocated memory, leading to your error.

Regarding your edit:
The passed argument gets `free`d in the thread. But your second argument has not allocated that memory unit (just as part of a bigger allocation), generating the problem.